# How do I set two different words to be equal in beyond compare 3

Tags: beyondcompare3

I'm trying to diff different versions of a program. The older version uses 1 and 0 to represent true and false while the new version uses the words true and false. Since these boolean values are everywhere, most of the file is 'different.' For now I've added 1,0,false,and true to unimportant in a custom file type, but this has a few unfortunate side effects (like not matching a 1 that changed to false.) So, does anyone know how to make true match to 1 and false to 0?

edit:

The language is a proprietary one for my company, but it's relatable to sql. An example of what I mean would be

```
select *
from fake_table ft
where ft.active_ind = 1
```

becomes

```
select *
from fake_table ft
where ft.active_ind = true
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What language are you using? Show some code. Be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Beyond Compare 3 or 4 Pro license, you can use Replacements in the Text Compare to show the differences as a match. Replacements are a pro only feature, if you have a BC3 or BC4 Standard license, then you'll have to use unimportant text.

1. In the **Text Compare**, click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
2. Go to the **Replacements** tab. Click **New** (BC3) or **+** (BC4).
3. Text to find: 1
4. Replace with: True

After you define the replacements, 1 on the left matched with True on the right will be colored as a match if **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is on.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't think this situation is common enough for me to get an upgraded license, so I'll have to continue with my hacky version. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you want to evaluate Replacements, you can put Beyond Compare back into trial mode temporarily by renaming the file that contains your license key. File is either "c:\program files\beyond compare 4\BC4Key.txt" or "%appdata%\scooter software\beyond compare 4\BC4Key.txt". https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_evalpro